# Populating the subject line of an email with the first line, of its body, that contains text

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

The team at my office spends a lot of time copying and pasting the first line of an article in the body and pasting it in the subject line.

I found a solution that takes the first line of the body and sets it as the subject.
The problem is that there are always two-three blank lines above the first line of text in the body.
The solution sets the subject as `" ".`

Is there a way to either delete the empty lines at the top, or skip over them and set the subject as being the first line of text?

Shirley Zhang from DataNumen provided the code.

The VBA code I have been using:

```
Private WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set objInspectors = Outlook.Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail And Inspector.CurrentItem.subject = "" Then
       Inspector.CurrentItem.subject = " "
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objMailDocument As Word.Document
Dim objMailSelection As Word.Selection

If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
    Set objMail = Item

    If Len(Trim(objMail.subject)) = 0 Then
        Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set objMailSelection = objMailDocument.Application.Selection

        objMailDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
        objMailSelection.MoveEnd wdLine

        'Take first line of body as subject
        objMail.subject = objMailSelection.Text
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't test, but maybe try adding a couple more `objMailSelection.MoveEnd wdLine` lines after the first one?

Comment: It works but only in some cases. Too few and the subject stays blank, too many and the subject line integrates several lines of the body.

Comment: Can you show couple of examples of the first line of the body-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If Len(Trim(objMail.subject)) = 0 Then
     'Take first line of body as subject
     objMail.subject = FirstLineOfText(objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor)
End If
```

Function to return first line of text:

```
Function FirstLineOfText(doc As Word.Document)
    Dim p As Word.Paragraph, rng
    For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
        'Find the first paragraph with content
        If Len(p.Range.Text) > 2 Then
            'select the start point of the paragraph
            doc.Range(p.Range.Start, p.Range.Start).Select
            'extend the selection to include the whole line
            doc.Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            FirstLineOfText = Trim(doc.Application.Selection.Text) '<<EDITED
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next p
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I tried this but I get a run time error saying the object variable is not set for the line "FirstLineOfText = Trim(Selection.Text)"

Comment: Sorry I missed the application context for the selection (as included in the previous line)

Comment: It works beautifully. I can't tell you how much time you have saved for me and for my colleagues. They'll be really happy when I tell them.Thank you very, very much Mr Williams

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
   Set objMail = Item

   If Len(Trim(objMail.Subject)) = 0 Then
       Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
       Set objMailSelection = objMailDocument.Application.Selection

       objMailDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
       objMailSelection.MoveEnd wdLine

       'Loop until we find some text
       Do While objMailSelection.Text = ""
          objMailSelection.MoveEnd wdLine
       Loop

       'Take first line of body as subject
       objMail.Subject = objMailSelection.Text
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I'm still not getting anything in the subject line when there are line breaks/ empty lines above it.

Comment: The more I look at the code the less I understand why it does not work. This is because there is indeed a subject in the email. It does not come back as "no subject"; it is blank. It would therefore make sense that the loop be activated. Several iterations of the wdline do effectively move down the message. I tried the solution that someone else posted that involved repeating that line. It worked, but the problem was that it would start catching the text on the lines below the relevant one as well. Truly, I do not understand...

Comment: @Louis When you say "catching the text on the lines below the relevant one", what do you mean? Is it separated by a carriage return?

Comment: the subject line will be populated by the lines that follow the relevant one as well, if I just insert half a dozen of these: objMailSelection.MoveEnd wdLine

Answer (score 0):

*Have you tried using [Regular Expression (regex or regexp for short)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)*

https://regex101.com/r/msJ13L/2

> [image]

---

> ```
> "^\w(.*)$"
> ```

***`^`*** asserts position at start of a line

***`\w`*** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

*1st Capturing Group **`(.*)`***

***`.*`*** matches any character (except for line terminators)

***`*`*** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

***`$`*** asserts position at the end of a line
Global pattern flags

***`m`*** modifier: multi line. Causes **`^`** and **`$`** to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

---

*VBA Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Matches As Variant        
    Dim Item As MailItem
    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.selection(1)

    Dim RegExp As Object
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    Dim Pattern As String
    Pattern = "^\w(.*)$"
    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = Pattern
         Set Matches = .Execute(Item.Body)
    End With

    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Matches(0) ' Print on Immediate Window
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not Found "
    End If

    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @0m3r for your answer. I tried what you wrote but I could not get it to work. As my knowledge of VBA is very limited I have no doubt this is a mistake on my end.